# R - How to create a data frame from a data frame with conditions?

Tags: r

I have a data frame that has many columns, but I want to create another data frame that only has the columns race and spouse. I have this sample of data.

```
  gender name    race realm  spouse
1  Female Adanel  Men  Gondor  Not Married
2  Male   Lagduf  Orc  Mordor  Married
2  Male   Boromir Men  Gondor  Married
```

I would like to create another data frame with race and spouse (where the creature is "married") so that I can plot a graph from it showing the marriage variation between races. The only data that should appear in the new data frame would be the following one:

```
  race spouse
1 Orc  Married
2 Men  Married
```

I would like to get the columns race and spouse(where the creature is "Married"). I have tried something like this:

```
marriedCreatures <- data %>% filter(spouse == "Married" & race)
```

As I've recently started working with R I don't know how I am supposed to create this new data frame from other data frame's columns.

I would appreciate if anyone could help me with that.

Thanks!

Comment: Fitst load `dplyr` with `library(dplyr)`, and then do:  `data %>% filter(spouse == "Married" ) %>% select(race, spouse)`

Comment: Thanks, it also worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(
  gender = c("Female", "Male", "Male"),
  name = c("Adanel", "Lagduf", "Boromir"),
  race = c("Men", "Orc", "Men"),
  spouse = c("Not married", "Married", "Married")
)

library(dplyr)

# base R
marriedCreatures <- df[df$spouse == "Married", c("race", "spouse")]
marriedCreatures

# dplyr
marriedCreatures <- df %>%
  dplyr::filter(spouse == "Married") %>%
  dplyr::select(race, spouse)
marriedCreatures
```

If prefer the dplyr version, but a one-liner should be nice too :-)

Comment: hm, hard to tell without the actual data what could have happened. The example data works and should also work for your data. Maybe post your exact code, I only could explain it with a spelling mistake

Comment: I found out why I thought the base R was wrong, because I haven't seen that when he was printed in the console it has skipped some numbers. For example: 
`833      Dwarf Married
840      Elf      Married
846      Men Married`                                                                                                                Thank you verry much

Comment: great, if my answer helped you, please accept it :-)

Answer (score 1):

An option with `base R`

```
subset(df, spouse == "Married", select = c("race", "spouse"))
```